# Swap o replaced an Engine in Kia Sorento 2013 Can i use a 2016 Kia Sorento Engine?

Tags: kia, engine-swap, swap, sorento

Kia Sorento 2.4 L 2013 4 cyl
I like to know what model and year of Engines Can I use for replaced my Engine

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the same engine was used from 2011-2015.  So no, the 2016 engine is not compatible.  Check with your engine supplier to be sure.  They should be knowledgeable about fitment.

Note that even with the same basic engine, accessories, sensors, controls, etc. may be different between years.  You may need to swap parts from your old engine onto the new one to make it fit.

Comment: “Not compatible”... a Merlin engine was put in a Rolls Royce... just have to solve the engineering issues. But if all you expect is to bolt-in and drive off...